Any way to typify model methods?
I have a peewee model. for example that looks kinda:
class GroupEntity(Base):
    id: UUID = UUIDField(unique=True, primary_key=True, default=uuid4())
    user_id: UUID = ForeignKeyField(User, backref='groups')
    title: str = CharField(max_length=256)
    type: GroupTypeEnum = CharField(choices=GROUP_TYPES)
    parent_id: UUID = UUIDField(null=True)
    price: int = SmallIntegerField(null=True)
    created_at: float = BigIntegerField(default=time.time())

    class Meta:
        table_name = TableNamesEnum.GROUP_ENTITY.value

well now i want to create instance of that model in my function
    group_entity: Group = Group.create(
        title='best group',
        type=GroupTypeEnum.Channel,
        user_id=user_entity.id
        )

that works fine, but i have no any hints about fields i have to pass
i checked method create of Base (peewee base model) and i saw there

(method) def create(**query: Any) -> Any
so i guess there is no existing solution of that problem

I tried to override create method like
class GroupEntity(Base):
    id: UUID = UUIDField(unique=True, primary_key=True, default=uuid4())
    user_id: UUID = ForeignKeyField(User, backref='groups')
    title: str = CharField(max_length=256)
    type: GroupTypeEnum = CharField(choices=GROUP_TYPES)
    parent_id: UUID = UUIDField(null=True)
    price: int = SmallIntegerField(null=True)
    created_at: float = BigIntegerField(default=time.time())

    class Meta:
        table_name = TableNamesEnum.GROUP_ENTITY.value

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, user_id: UUID, title: str, type: GroupTypeEnum, 
               parent_id: Optional[UUID] = None, price: Optional[int] = None) -> 'GroupEntity':
        return super().create(
            user_id=user_id,
            title=title,
            type=type,
            parent_id=parent_id,
            price=price
        )

that worked nice, but i am not sure about that solution, cause that's a scary thing to override create method (and other, not typed methods) in every model
i hope there is more cleaner solution

Your IDE will need to have knowledge of what peewee / pydantic models are and how their properties map to a create method; you might want to check if there's a specific extension for your IDE to handle this.

didnt find anything usefull(
